# How to recognize that a parent page is left from within an iframe?

Tags: javascript, iframe

I would like to execute a function from within an iframe before page is unloaded to send data to my Analytics tool. But I am in an iframe.

I do only know:

`window.onbeforeunload = function(){ ... }`

But it seems like that doesn't work from the iframe, my function is not executed.

I also found this:

```
var iframe = document.getElementById('iframe');
iframe.load(
    function(){
        iframe.contentWindow.onbeforeunload = function(){
            myFunction();
        }
    }
)
```

but it didn't work either.

Is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
var iframe = document.getElementById('iframe');

iframe.addEventListener( "load", function(e) {
    alert('content loaded'); 
});
iframe.addEventListener( "beforeunload", function(e) {
    alert('content reloaded'); 
    myFunction();
});
```

Comment: I want to do this from the code of the iframe. I tried the code you posted but I used window instead of iframe. The 'content loaded' worked, but 'content reloaded' didn't appear.

Comment: I am trying to get to know when the parent page is unloaded, but it seems like the iframe content is not unloaded?